# Calling a functional forwardRef component React

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm building a component where it calls a component which is passed down through props. The component uses forward ref in it, and so I'm unable to call it. It shows `itemComponent`.

Code:

Parent component:

```
export default function DNDList({
  items,
  idKey = 'id',
  itemComponent,
  listStyles,
  hideParentList
}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dndReducer, items);
  const previewRef = useRef(null);

  const onMove = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'switch',
      data: {
        to: hoverIndex,
        from: dragIndex
      }
    });
  };

  console.log(itemComponent);

  const renderItems = () => (
    <>
      {state.map((item, i) => (
        <Item previewRef={previewRef} id={item[idKey]} key={item[idKey]} index={i} onMove={onMove}>
          {/* Main Code, Item Component is a forward Ref, see example below */}
          {itemComponent ? itemComponent({ item, ref:previewRef }) : item[idKey]}
        </Item>
      ))}
    </>
  );

  return hideParentList ? (
    renderItems()
  ) : (
    <ul className={listStyles}>{renderItems()}</ul>
  );
}
```

Example of `itemComponent`:

```
const TemplateListBlock = forwardRef(({ item }, ref) => {
  const onRemoveSender = () => {};

  console.log(ref);

  return (
    <li className={`${styles.contentBlock}`} data-template="true">
      <div className="drag-handler no-select" ref={ref}>
        <Menu />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.templateSettings}>
        <TemplateSenderOptions message={item} onRemoveSender={onRemoveSender} />
      </div>
      <p className={commonStyles.senderWrapper}>
        <span className={commonStyles.sender}>{item.from}</span> will appear
        here.
      </p>
    </li>
  );
});
```

component used in the first component:

```
function Item({ id, index, onMove, children }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);


  drag(drop(ref));

  return (
    <li style={{ opacity }} key={id} ref={ref} data-handler-id={handlerId}>
      {children}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: How do you pass `itemComponent` to `DNDList`?

Comment: <DNDList itempComponent={TemplateListBlock} />

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `previewRef` like so: `<Item previewRef={previewRef}...`
Try passing it like so: `<Item ref={previewRef}...`